# How to import custom content type in XML?

Tags: 7, nodes, importing-exporting

I have installed the newest Drupal 7.12 and need to import custom content type data exported from custom CMS but ... don't know what is the correct XML structure.

1) I have added `<MY_CUSTOM_CONTENT_TYPE>` into Structure
- added about 20 fields

2) prepare Import feed

- Attach to content type: Use standalone form
- Fetcher: file upload
- Parser: Sitemap parser - Parse Sitemap XML format feeds.
- Processor: Node processor
- Node processor settings: Text format: plain text; Content type: `<MY_CUSTOM_CONTENT_TYPE>`

3) I have exported XML file with content (probably with the wrong XML structure)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<articles>
<article type="MY_CUSTOM_CONTENT_TYPE">
     <title>1234</title>
     <custom_1>1234</custom_1>
     <custom_2>abcd</custom_2>
     ...
     <custom_20>...20...</custom_20>
</article>
</articles>
```

3) after loading XML file getting "There are no new nodes."

I can prepare XML structure when exporting content, but want to know how to do it.

Comment: are the fields mapped correctly in "Proccessor > Mapping" and with unique GUID ?

Comment: I don't have any "Mapping for Node processor" options becouse don't know how it works.

Comment: This link http://drupal.org/node/919448 helps

Comment: I had a very similar problem. Turns out I was missing the GUID. Added it on the Processor>Mapping page and mapped it to the Nid of my exported node and things started working.

Answer (score 1):

In my case an error *"There are no new nodes"* was caused by a wrong xml context in the xpath parser setting.

In your case should be: `//article` and not only: `article`.

This is because `//article` in xpath is equivalent to say *"all the article tags"*.
If you put only *article* in the xpath, context feeds does not import anything.